# verify and verifyNoMoreInteractions to gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, junit, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to rewrite test written from JUnit for gtest: I faced the following lines:

```
when(obj1.peek(300)).thenReturn(true);
verify(obj1, times(1)).peek(333);
verify(obj2, times(1)).log(400);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(obj1);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(obj2);
```

And I don't know how to deal with that.
Please help me.

P.S. How to get a percentage of coverage from gtest/gmock?

Comment: for coverage i think they have gcov. but i have never really look at it so I am simply sharing this little piece of info: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html

Comment: or this is probabluy better: http://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks like you're after google mock's `EXPECT_CALL()`.

Comment: I looked at it, but the problem is with verifyNoMoreInteractions()

Comment: Please provide more info about environment/compiler/IDE you are using, so appropriate code coverage tool can be recommended.

Comment: Linux, CLion, gcc 4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your mock classes for objects `obj1` and `obj2` are named `MyMockClass1` and `MyMockClass2`, here is how you do this using **gmock**:

```
testing::StrictMock<MyMockClass1> obj1;
testing::StrictMock<MyMockClass2> obj2;

EXPECT_CALL(obj1, peek(300)).WillOnce(Return(true));
EXPECT_CALL(obj1, peek(333)).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(obj2, loog(400)).Times(1);
```

Usage of `testing::StrictMock` treats every uninteresting method call on that mock object as an error, which should be what you want to achieve with `verifyNoMoreInteractions`.

As far as code coverage goes, I personally use the Visual Studio add-on for **gtest**, which then enables you to see code coverage of tests. Since you cannot use the same, then the best bet is probably **Gcov** suggested by @Stefano.